# ArrayOutofBounds with tokens of variable amount of words

Tags: java, token

I'm trying to read commands from a text file that might have different number of words.  I'm trying to use IF statements so that I don't get the array out of bounds exception.
Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.
Here is the section of code where it occurs.

```
    read = new Scanner(new File("Phone.txt"));

    //this will loop thru file until end of file
    while (read.hasNext())
    {

    whole = read.nextLine().trim();
    String[] tokens = whole.split(" ");//array to split up line
    command = tokens[0].toLowerCase();//all lines will have at least one word
    if (tokens.length > 0)//if more than one word, 2nd will be name
    {
        name1st.setFirst(tokens[1]);
    }

    if (tokens.length > 1)//if more than one word, 3rd will be phone #
    {
        phone = tokens[2];
    }
        switch (command)
        {
            case "add":
                nameList.add(name1st, phone);
                break;
            case "locate":
                nameList.getValue(name1st);
                break;
            case "remove":
                    nameList.remove(name1st);
                break;
            case "print":
                    nameList.display();
        }//end switch

    }//end while
```

Comment: Where is your exception?

Comment: The length of the array is equal to 1 + the maximum valid index.  Your if() statements aren't checking the right numbers:  You can't use token[1] unless token.length >= 2, can't use token[2] unless token.length >= 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indexing starts from 0.And The length of the array is equal to number of elements in array.

```
    if (tokens.length > 1)//if more than one word, 2nd will be name
    {
        name1st.setFirst(tokens[1]);
    }

    if (tokens.length > 2)//if more than one word, 3rd will be phone #
    {
        phone = tokens[2];
    }
```

You could correct your code as above.

Answer (score 0):

OKay,

figured it out.  length is not the same as index.  if it has idex of 0, it has length of 1 so I had to up my conditions in the if by 1.  Then it ran.  Thanks for anyone who also were working on this